# C expected expression before struct error

Tags: c, struct

Why I´m getting the error expected expression before struct at static void print_abc(struct abc); in main function?

```
struct abc{
int a;
int b;
int c;
};
static void print_abc(struct abc){
printf("&i &i &d",a,b,c);
}

int main(void){
static void print_abc(struct abc);
}
```

Comment: `static void print_abc(struct abc);` that is not how you call a function.

Comment: And there are no specifier as `"&i &i &d"` which you use in `printf` to print `int` variables .

Comment: And how to call a function? The values for a,b,c will be declared in another function

Comment: There's also no `a, b, c` in scope for `print_abc()`.

Comment: You apparently have quiete some missconception about programming in general (there are issues not only realted to C). I'd recommend to start reading a C book or a tutorial, course, etc.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Please read any C tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

## 1

The keyword *static* is a keyword and does not need to be added when trying to call a function marked with *static*. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_(keyword)) for more information.

## 2

You also cannot implicitily convert a structure to another data-type. You are trying to do this in the *print_abc* function. You need to explicitly access the member variables.

## 3

&i and &d is not a valid placeholder to insert integers when using the *printf* function. Use %d instead, see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for more info.

The code should be:

```
struct abc{
int a;
int b;
int c;
};
static void print_abc(struct abc){
printf("%d %d %d",abc.a,abc.b,abc.c);
}

int main(void){
void print_abc(struct abc);
}
```